# x86 NASM changes value at address not passed as parameter

Tags: assembly, x86, scanf, nasm, lldb

I am noticing some peculiar behavior with scanf in NASM assembly code. I have two calls to scanf:

```
mov rdi, fmt
mov rsi, r14
call _scanf
```

and

```
mov rdi, fmt
mov rsi, r15
call _scanf
```

where `fmt` is declared in the `data` section as:

```
section .data
fmt: db "%d", 0
```

Before the first `scanf`, the addresses in r14 and r15 are:

```
r14 = 0x0000000000002104
r15 = 0x0000000000002105
```

In LLDB, executing `me read -fd -c1` on either of these addresses outputs 0.

After entering "2" for the first `scanf`, the value in 0x0000000000002104 is thankfully 2.

After entering "2" for the second `scanf`, the value in 0x0000000000002105 is 2. However, now the value in 0x0000000000002104 is 514.

I am experiencing similar changes in memory after calls to `scanf` in other places and will reproduce them if needed but wanted to know if anyone has experienced this.

Comment: Those addresses 2104 and 2105 are one byte apart but you are using "%d" which will fill in a 4 byte integer potentially clobbering the bytes after the location you are trying to read into. You lack a minimal complete verifiable example. You should just post your code and we can get a better understanding of it. Is this on MacOS? and did you set the _AL_ register to zero before the scanf calls?

Comment: 514 is 0x0202, that is, the dword combination of the byte values in 2105 and 2104.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: you can use `[mcve]` in comments: it expands to [mcve].  This is almost too minimal, but I think this specific question is answerable based on this.  I guess you want to check what width the OP is using to read the integer values after scanf, to make sure it's dword, matching the width of `int` which `%d` stores?

Comment: In other words, 0x2014 and 0x2015, if used as addresses to 32 bit integers, **overlap**. If scanf writes "2" to 0x2014, it will write 2 to 0x2014, **0 to 0x2015**, 0 to 0x2016 and 0 to 0x2017. Writing to 0x2015 will write **2 to 0x2015** and 0 to 0x2016..0x2018 each. Now if you read that from 0x2014, there will be a **2 at 0x2014, a 2 at 0x2015**, a 0 at 0x2016 and a 0 at ox2017. That means you get 0x00000202, which is 514.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: you were right. I was using the incorrect format for how many bytes I was reserving. If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it since it solved my issue.

Comment: Post the answer as an answer, not an edit to your question, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously, I was using `%d` as the format for scanf which reads 4 bytes. However the addresses in r14 and r15 were reserved in the `bss` section for only 1 byte. I changed this so that they now reserve 4 bytes and the program works as expected.